# How to create InstallShield Setup of VSTO (COM) Addin for Excel using Installshield 2008

Tags: excel, vsto, installshield, comaddin

I have created a com addIn in Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) for Excel 2010 and I want to create a single exe setup file for end user. I have googled this issue but all I can find are the solutions using Visual studio. I want to create setup with Installshield program.

Comment: did you see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx ?

Comment: Did you mean the reverna installshield? https://www.revenera.com/ because the answers seem to be describing the windows installer method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) in details for InstallShield Limited Edition (it should be very similar to Installshield 2008). It is a standard installation procedure except for 2 important points :

- You must ensure that the VSTO runtime is installed on the client machine.
- You must create a set of registry keys to enable the Office application to discover and load the VSTO Add-in. [see here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx)

Comment: Did following the steps in the answer help with creating the installer? If yes, can someone explain more about the creating the registry keys step? I am trying to package my vsto excel toolbar using the windows installer and I am having problems building the installer. So maybe more details could help me see what I might have missed there.