# Create an installer using Installshield for Excel XLL Add-in

Tags: deployment, installshield, excel-dna, xll

I created an xll add-in which contains some user defined functions for excel using excel dna, now i want to deploy this add-in on the customer's pc, for that i would like to create an installer using installshield. is this possible to be done with installshield? 
Have you an idea or any suggestion how to create an installer for my xll addin please ?
Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create InstallShield Setup of VSTO (COM) Addin for Excel using Installshield 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791026/how-to-create-installshield-setup-of-vsto-com-addin-for-excel-using-installshi)

Comment: This is about how to install a vsto add-in or i'm working with xll (excel dna) add-in

Comment: It is the same... BTW: Have you considered: WixInstaller - https://github.com/Excel-DNA/WiXInstaller... Also this is not IS but nice instructions for a similar product: https://jiripik.com/2017/02/25/use-advanced-installer-excel-dna-project/ I think there is enough there to get you going...

Comment: I'm asked to do it with installshield and i found this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdSuGENg3W4, i did the same steps but when i open excel and try to call my functions i don't find them, they are not added

Comment: Look at the last link I posted, at the vbs script ie. https://cdn.jiripik.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/25143413/20150705-exceldna-advancedinstallersetup18.png

Comment: Office addins come in two flavors that I know of.  COM native and .NET VSTO.   Do you know how to manually deploy this add in?  If so, pointers could be given on how to translate that into WiX requirements.

Comment: Yes i can add them manually, i open excel => click Options => Add-ins => select Excel Add-ins in the drop down list and click the button Go then click the Browse button and select the xll file in the bin/debug of my class library project and finally ok, i want to create an installer that can do this automatically